# Java Spring - How to use value from application.properties with @WithUserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I want to use a value from `application.properties` with the `@WithUserDetails()` annotation for my tests.

My current code:

```
@Value("${user.admin}")
private String ADMIN;

@Test
@WithUserDetails(ADMIN)
public void foo() { 
}
```

displays the error "Attribute value must be constant"

I am using junit4 with spring runner

Comment: @Deadpool That just appears to be passing the string ${user.admin} as the value as opposed to getting the value from the application.properties

Comment: Try making the variable static final. sample: private static final String ADMIN;

Comment: @Clover nope doesn't work, thanks though friend!

Comment: Well, you should not write simple member variables in UPPERCASE, as this is usually only be used for constants. `ADMIN` is not a constant, and this is your problem (Java annotations only accept constants as parameters, i.e. string literals or `static final` members with a string literal as value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this cannot be done, the Java compiler won't allow it as it doesn't consider the value from `@Value()` to be a constant at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

java has built in capabilities to read a .properties file and JUnit has built in capabilities to run setup code before executing a test suite.

java reading properties:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileReader(new File("application.properties")));
```

[junit startup documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize_3)

put those 2 together and you should have what you need.

**But yes the minimum requirment is you have `application.properties` file in your `test->resources` package as well.**